# OnApplicationFocus and OnApplicationPause called when enter the game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make my game save the data when the game lost focus or paused, but OnApplicationFocus() and Paused() function also called when I start the game. Is there a way to only call these 2 functions when resume from paused or lost focus? My game is calling load() 3 times everytime I start the game.

```
void Awake()
{
    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("firstTimePlayer"))
    {
        load();
    }
    else
    {
        playerData.money = 100;
        playerData.coffeeBean = 100;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("firstTimePlayer", 0);
    }
}

void OnApplicationFocus(bool hasFocus)
{
    if (!hasFocus)
    {
        save();
    }
    else
    {
        load();
    }
}

void OnApplicationPause(bool isPaused)
{
    if (isPaused)
    {
        save();
    }
    else
    {
        load();
    }
}

void OnApplicationQuit()
{
    save();
}
```

Comment: Isn't using `OnApplicationPause(true / false)` is enough?

Comment: from what I understand Pause and focus means different action on mobile and  I'm trying to be safe here. But even if I only use Pause(true / false), the game will still call the Pause function when I enter the game.

Comment: If you sure it will call in enter game , Can you ignore first call?

Comment: @TimChang what do you mean by ignore first call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may able to solve this by adding a flag to make sure content of `load()` only called once until it is needed.

Call `backFromIdel` instead.

```
bool loaded = false;

void backFromIdel()(
    if (loaded)
        return;
    load();
    loaded = true;
}

void save(){
    loaded = false;
    ......
}
```